# How to install contour plugin for QGIS Wien on Linux mint?

Tags: qgis, contour, linux

When trying to install install contour plugin for QGIS Wien on Linux mint I get error "The contour plugin is disabled as it requires python modules numpy, matplotlib, and shapely which are not all installed".

the software required does not seem to be available in the repos and version would be important as well. Any one know the fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is outlining what you need to do. The plugin needs numpy, matplotlib and shapely to be installed in your system.

Try going to software manager from Menu > Administration > Software Manager and then in the search box type those three names and it should appear straight in your software list. Install these python libraries one by one and then try to reinstall the QGIS countour plugin. It should work. You can restart your system if the installed plugins are not recognised.

[image: matplotlib search result in Linux Mint Sofware Manager]

Comment: Thanks I was using synaptic but package manager was clearer

Comment: @lewis pelase mark the answer as accepted if it helped you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/someone-answers

Comment: So marking as accepted is not so obvious.

Comment: Besides I like an air of mystery.